# To take property?

Tags: verbs

The phrase : Take property of (something from someone) in the same sense of the verb 'to appropriate', as "The police took property of the stolen goods" or even  "I am going to take property of your car if you don't pay me back sson " is grammatically correct or acceptable?

Comment: Well, generally it would be "took *the* property", and even then "The police took the property" is awkwardly phrased, especially with "of the stolen goods" tacked on.  I think the word you're searching for is "possession" -- "The police took *possession* of the stolen goods," or "I am going to take *possession* of your car if you don't pay me back soon."

Comment: *Possession* is not the same thing as *ownership*, though an old adage has it that *possession is nine points of the law*. I have always supposed it to mean that if someone has possession, there is no more than a one in ten chance the owner will be able to assert his/her rights to the extent of getting it back.

Comment: Great answers ! Both really useful to me. I apppreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are thinking of *confiscate*?

Comment: or "seize"?  I believe I have heard of police auctions of "seized" vehicles, for instance ..... When a city wants to take real property, such as a house, to make room for some supposed public improvement such as a highway or an airport, they first "condemn" it, then seize it (well, they pay a price, but one that they set, not the buyer) This used to be called "eminent domain".

Answer (score 0):

[To sequester:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sequester)  can fit the context you are describing: (TFD)

> - (Law) To take temporary possession of (property) as security against legal claims.